# Have a doubt about God in general?

Tags: doubt, logic, theology

God is the cause of all things, and the creator of all things. God is eternal, never ending and timeless, with no beginning or end. Him and all of his attributes are eternal and never ending. This might help you understand this question. Do you understand eternality in the abstract sense, do you have any abstraction that allows you to understand eternality? To put it, eternality here means never ending , however its the timeless eternality, something with no beginning and no end, God has no beginning and no end, if something has no beginning you can't apply seconds to it to count how long its existed because that doesn't apply to it. Unfortunately I've argued with lots of really dumb people, so I'm just going to say right now that the fact I'm showing a seeming contradiction is showing that I am starting to feel God isn't real, because him being the first cause seems to violate the law of non contradiction.

This post is showing a contradiction in the existence of a first cause, meaning maybe its not possible for it to exist. You might not get this immediately so look at the second paragraph and read again, for now just read this:can you get this: a first cause is eternal, meaning it is timeless, never ending. You can't apply seconds to it if it is eternal, all of its processes are eternal, its process of causation is also eternal,, all of its processes are eternal, and its process of causation is eternal, thus since its causation process doesn't end, it will continue to cause forever and ever, being eternal in the timeless sense, without a beginning and end. Now, I say this: if a first causes causation doesn't end, it will continue to cause and cause the exact same thing as its causation of that thing doesn't end, however, this means that the law of identity would be violated, because how can there be two of the same thing , if it continues to cause that thing then that would mean there are two things that are the same, but everything is equal to itself, it would go agains't the law of identity, so how do we overcome this contradiction? I thought of something like,non beings don't have properties, and this is important because of the fact that we can say that our abstract understanding is wrong, but then I thought of this: maybe we can't define the being abstractly since its trancendent, and other things but it seems i need help from smeone else on this.

Mind you, an inherent aspect of a first cause is its ability to cause, and its actual act of causing is also never ending, inherent here means it exists as a permanent aspect of it, because we know causation is an aspect of the first cause that is inherent to it, as if it wasn't permanent it would mean it had an aspect that was added to it, which is impossible because is eternal and timeless and can't change. So its causation being an inherent aspect of it is also eternal, and the process, non timely process which takes place in causing it is also never ending. There we go

Comment: can you clarify some of your points (`everything connected to him doesn't end do you understand the law of identity`-what is everything (is mankind included), what law of identity are you referencing? `Two things cannot share the exact same properties` - yes/no (depends on the scale of the thing), `he will cause the exact same thing` - can you provide an example of what you are talking about?)?

Comment: this basicaly means, all his attributes connected to him that are inherent attributes and properties of him dont end

Comment: will is a par tof god, his will doenst end, his will and everyhting about it that is eternal doesnt end, his decision to cause things doesnt end

Comment: @depperm ihere look up

Comment: None of this is clear to me. I suggest that considerably more clarity and detail will be needed before there can be a response. And, in any case, this is all philosophical and metaphysical. I do not see that it is about Christianity. SE-C is about _comparative Christianity_ analysing what self-identifying 'Christians' believe and do. Questions about deity in a metaphysical sense are not relevant.

Comment: "he will cause the exact same thing" im not talking about a particular thing, im saying anyhting he causes involves  this

Comment: You can't ask a question like 'do Christians believe God is eternal ?' because the spectrum of worldwide 'christianity' contains massive disagreements about everything. You need to ask questions of a specific group who publish definitive literature to tell us what they believe. Reformed Presbyterians, yes, believe God is eternal.

Comment: As to 'proving' spiritual matters, well these things are discovered in one's own spiritual experience. And spiritual experience begins by discovering one's own sinfulness. That is to say, the genuine discovery of _one's own condition of spirit._ "Blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the kingdom of heaven" Matthew 5:3.

Comment: **Personified God** It is suggested that instead of wandering in the dark forest of philosophical dimness,  a person really interested in understanding the Concept (and Reality) of God, take a look at the Person of Jesus!  In Him dwells the fullness of God bodily. Looking unto Jesus there is understanding, and all you need to know to gain eternal life, as well as existential purpose and meaning!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your conundrum is that God is free. Radically free.

```
Why should the nations say,
    “Where is their God?”
Our God is in the heavens;
    he does all that he pleases.
(Psalm 115:2-3)
```

God is the uncaused cause. Nothing forces his hand or imposes a requirement upon Him to perform an action. This is axiomatic. There is no chain of causality that precedes Him, nor is any chain of causality proceeding from him determined by anything except God's will. No particular action must flow from God based on his attributes. His will may be to love, but how He displays that love in each instance is up to Him. The same, unchanging eternal attributes may give rise to a multiplicity of effects over time.

Our universe is the wedding of a causal material substrate that behaves in accordance with laws of cause and effect and a spiritual realm in which God is not bound by laws of cause and effect.

> He has made everything beautiful in its time. Also, he has put
> eternity into man's heart, yet so that he cannot find out what God has
> done from the beginning to the end. (Ecclesiastes 3:11)

If everything we see in our world was solely the result of chains of cause and effect, Solomon would be wrong and Ecclesiastes would be false. We could eventually figure it all out.

Expecting to resolve this problem on the terms that you desire is something God made impossible on purpose. Psalm 19 tells us of two ways that God's truths are communicated to us. One is natural revelation and is the deciphering of the laws of nature, but it is incomplete. The other is the special revelation of God's law and the gospel through the prophets. That is essential. It provides unprovable axioms upon which to build a true view of reality. Nature cannot provide all those axioms.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to say is: If God's will causes things, how can there be more than one thing, if that will is eternal and unchanging.

Well, there really is only one thing God's will causes: All of the universe, and it's entire history. All of this together, is the single thing caused that you are looking for. From a perspective outside of time, which I would assume this thought construct assumes God has, one could even say that causing happened exactly once. It only looks like "the will of God is causing something over and over" because we are inside of the thing that was/is/will be caused.

So really, the issue is resolved if you start seeing the universe and it's history as one thing that is caused, instead of many small unrelated things.

Answer (score 0):

The law of identity states that a thing is what it is. In other words, two things cannot be the same thing. However, some people argue that God is an exception to this law. They say that God is both eternal and unchanging, and that his causation is never-ending. This means that God is constantly causing the same things to happen, which some people believe is a contradiction.As for your question about how to refute the argument that God's causation is a contradiction, there is no easy answer. One way to refute the argument is to question the assumption that two things cannot be the same. You could argue that God is unique and special, and that he is therefore not subject to the same laws of logic as other things.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

I bear witness that the God of Abraham is real. Not only does He have real and true servants prophesying in his name but these servants prophesied about my past like Jesus prophesied to the Samaritan woman at the well that she has had **five husbands and the current one is not her husband.** Some future events of my life were also prophesied and this is no ordinary feat as the **Gift of Prophecy** is a gift that can only be given by the **Holy Spirit**. Demons and the devil cannot have those abilities because the gifts are not theirs to give. I do not know why **prophets** are hard to find in some parts of the world but they do prophesy and reveal God's purpose to man kind in my country.

I also happened to attend a high school where some of my classmates were practising witchcraft and they did not want me to find out about their dark or **secret arts(cross check with the arts the Egyptians performed to compete with Moses** but the Lord led me to the light, to these servants and I learnt that truth that every iota written in the Bible is true and will come to pass.

I am speaking from what I experienced and also learnt that those classmates were practising Satanism with human sacrifice involved. What I learnt from this ordeal is **that you can always seek God and you will always find Him**.

The servants clearly told me that your fellowship with our church is being fought in school because they fear that the **Holy Spirit or God who knows everything will put their secrets on the mountains for everyone to see lol**.

There was always this classmate who would come near to me with his locker and borrow me books, he did untold things to my books at home but the servants of God would always tell me like this in the same **exact way the classmate would approach me**

***There is a classmate who comes with his locker to sit next to you, that's where darkness comes in***

The statement above was one hundred percent correct and it was revealed to the servant of God via a vision because its exactly how he approached me with his locker and borrow me books.

**The God of Abraham is real and nothing in our past or future can block us from His Love, God loves you and would like to have a Father Son relationship with you**

Seek ye first his kingdom and all these other things shall be given to you.

I knew those friends for the hypocrites that they were and kept my distance.